# Onreadystatechange not not working after header redirection in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, userscripts, onreadystatechange

I have made a userscript for a forum that resizes images. It works great, except for after posting or editing where it redirects, where `onreadystatechange` does not fire in Google Chrome.

When viewing a thread, EG *SomeSite/forums.php?action=viewtopic&topicid=205362*, the userscript works.

After editing/posting, EG *SomeSite/forums.php?action=viewtopic&topicid=205362&page=p4976670#4976670*, the userscript doesn't work.

The problem lies with this code:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    //Call function
}};
```

I wait for all resources to be loaded, because the resizing is inconsistent otherwise on pages with many images.

The script works perfectly in Firefox with Greasemonkey.

Any idea why `onreadystatechange` does not fire on Chrome after a redirect? Is there a better way to wait for resources to have been loaded?

Comment: We need to see the *whole script*, especially the metadata block, in this case.  Linking to the actual target page, or a snapshot of its code may be necessary too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state whether you use the `@run-at` parameter but, [***by default***, Chrome userscripts are somewhat erratic about when they fire](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at).
That means that sometimes a userscript will fire before the `onload` event and sometimes it will fire after (by default).  If it's after the `onload` event, then `onreadystatechange` won't trigger.

To adapt to this behavior, either add `// @run-at document-end` to [the metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block), or replace that code snippet with:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", YourMainFunction, false);
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    YourMainFunction ();
}

function YourMainFunction {
    // DO ALL YOUR STUFF HERE...
}
```

In the latter case, `YourMainFunction()` will either wait for the load event (same as `readyState == "complete"`) or fire immediately if the event has already passed.  `YourMainFunction()` will only run once in either case.