# Google chrome is not executing all my <script>s

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, socket.io

I am making some sort of online game using html5, canvas, node and socket.io. The html for my game consists of a canvas tag, and then follows a list of  tags, some by source and some others inline. The layout is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="640" >
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>

    <!-- Scripts go here -->

</body>
</html>
```

In firefox my game works fine, but in chrome, it only executes the first two scripts:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script> 
    if(window.io) {
        var socket = io();
        socket.emit('identify', { client_type : 'game' });
    }
</script>
```

Those two scripts are correctly executed, but after that, chrome just ignores all other scripts, which are mostly defining functions and constants. For example, things like:

```
<script src="vector2.js" type="text/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
<script src="utils.js" type="text/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

I think it's relevant to mention that I'm using strict mode and some ES6 features such as let, but even if that was the problem I'd expect to see some output on the console. Instead, neither my console.logs nor any kind of error is printed.

Looking at the debugger I can see how the first two scripts are executed, and then it gets stuck on a loop in this piece of code (in the line pointed with a ->).

```
if (this.hasXDR()) {
    xhr.onload = function(){
        self.onLoad();
    };
    xhr.onerror = function(){
        self.onError(xhr.responseText);
    };
} else {
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
->      if (4 != xhr.readyState) return;
        if (200 == xhr.status || 1223 == xhr.status) {
            self.onLoad();
        } else {
            // make sure the `error` event handler that's user-set
            // does not throw in the same tick and gets caught here
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.onError(xhr.status);
```

Note that I didn't write this code and I can't really identify what this library is. I just can tell it's running inside this function in a loop.

What's going on? Why are my scripts not getting executed?

Comment: looks like a request is not completing, can you check your `network` tab in chrome to see pending requests ?

Comment: I can see the requests getting to my node server and sending the scripts back, also in the Network tab in chrome I can see all the scripts loaded just fine (note that I can also see its source, as if they were loaded, but no code seems to be executed).

Comment: Something to do with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594493/onreadystatechange-not-not-working-after-header-redirection-in-chrome

Comment: @Setzer22 on the network tab ensure you are looking at `XHR` requests..

Comment: @Pogrindis No pending requests on XHR tab either. There are 4 completed socket.io requests in it though.

Comment: @DavidBulté I'm not really sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figured out what was going on. Even though I haven't found a fix or workaround so far.

It had to do with labelling scripts as javascript version 1.7, doing that makes google chrome and chromium in my linux machine to completely ignore the script. Removing that type attribute makes the script load. But then ES6 features are not properly recognised by the browser.

I post this as an answer because it really answers my original question, however Better answers with the reason why this happens and possible fixes are more than welcome.

Comment: Sadly, I experienced the same behaviour. For me this means either my app runs on firefox OR on chrome for now. Or i need to remove all ES6 features... this is silly just because of this `version=1.7` string

Comment: One could serve different versions of the html page depending on the user's browser just to fix that particular issue. But the fact still remains that chrome is not properly implementing the ES6 standard yet, as many features are still missing...

Comment: yes and yes... even more time to invest to solve this issue which will be gone soon enough I guess. I made a fallback and removed ES6 features for now :-P